# Import and update or add new row if it doesn't exist CSV MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have an automated inventory I'm creating for someone and I had the updating completed correctly. The values were updating successfully. However, I noticed the mysql I was using was NOT adding new rows that were appearing in the updates. I tried to get this to work on my own, but I've had no luck thus far. Can someone shed a little light into why this isn't working? The main table is    ´product_list´

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_update_table (SKU VARCHAR(50), PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(255), QTY smallint(6), COMMENTS text);

// Create Temporary Table

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/useraccount/products.csv' INTO TABLE temp_update_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (SKU, PRODUCT_NAME, QTY);

// Insert CSV Contents into table

UPDATE product_list INNER JOIN temp_update_table on temp_update_table.SKU = product_list.SKU SET product_list.QTY = temp_update_table.QTY;

// Update Current Quantities to match new ones.

INSERT INTO product_list(SKU, PRODUCT_NAME, QTY) SELECT NEW.SKU, NEW.PRODUCT_NAME, NEW.QTY  FROM temp_update_table as NEW LEFT JOIN product_list as OLD ON OLD.SKU = NEW.SKU WHERE OLD.SKU IS NULL:"

// If there are any new rows, add them (This is the line where the problem lies?)

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_update_table;
// Remove Temp Table
```

There aren't any SQL errors.. so it's me calling things incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manged to solve my issue using on duplicate key like so after loading the temp table:

```
insert into product_list(SKU,PRODUCT_NAME,QTY)
select SKU, PRODUCT_NAME, QTY FROM temp_update_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE QTY = values(QTY);
```